# Calculate total and subtotals from JavaScript array on two categories

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I'm trying to add up three totals: `totalPoints`, `monthlyTotals`, and `monthlyByType` using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

I have `totalPoints`, and `monthlyTotals` working great but I'm stuck on the last one, `monthlyByType`.

Here's the array that I need to iterate:

```
const gamePointsArray = [
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg1',
    gameType: 1,
    gameMonth: 4,
    gamePoints: 4000,
  },
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg2',
    gameType: 2,
    gameMonth: 2,
    gamePoints: 7000,
  },
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg3',
    gameType: 2,
    gameMonth: 0,
    gamePoints: 3000,
  },
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg4',
    gameType: 1,
    gameMonth: 8,
    gamePoints: 25000,
  },
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg5',
    gameType: 3,
    gameMonth: 8,
    gamePoints: 5000,
  },
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg6',
    gameType: 3,
    gameMonth: 3,
    gamePoints: 10000,
  },
  {
    gamePlayId: 'ggg7',
    gameType: 2,
    gameMonth: 3,
    gamePoints: 5000,
  },

]
```

Here's my reducer:

```
const gamePointsReducer = (acc, game) => {

  const { gamePlayId, gameType, gameMonth, gamePoints,} = game

  if (!acc['totalPoints']) {
    acc['totalPoints'] = gamePoints
  } else {
    acc['totalPoints'] += gamePoints
  }

  if (!acc['monthlyTotals']) {
    acc['monthlyTotals'] = {
      0: 0,
      1: 0,
      2: 0,
      3: 0,
      4: 0,
      5: 0,
      6: 0,
      7: 0,
      8: 0,
      9: 0,
      10: 0,
      11: 0,
    }
  }

  acc.monthlyTotals[`${gameMonth}`] += gamePoints 

  if (!acc['monthByType']) {
    acc['monthByType'] = {
      0: {},
      1: {},
      2: {},
      3: {},
      4: {},
      5: {},
      6: {},
      7: {},
      8: {},
      9: {},
      10: {},
      11: {},
    }
  }

  acc.monthByType[`${gameMonth}`] += {
    [`${gameType}`]: gamePoints
  }

  return acc


}



const monthTotalsObj = gamePointsArray.reduce(gamePointsReducer, {}) 
console.log('Game Points totals obj', monthTotalsObj);
```

I'm needing the end result `Object` to look like this:

```
{
  totalPoints: 59000,
  monthlyTotals: {
    0: 3000,
    1: 0,
    2: 7000,
    3: 15000,
    4: 4000,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 30000,
    9: 0,
    10: 0,
    11: 0,
  },
  monthByType: {
    0: {
      2: 3000,
    },
    1: {},
    2: {
      2: 7000,
    },
    3: {},
    4: {
      1: 4000,
    },
    5: {},
    6: {},
    7: {},
    8: {
      1: 25000,
      3: 5000,
    },
    9: {},
    10: {},
    11: {},
  }
}
```

Comment: Will there be only one entry for a `gameType`
   - `gameMonth` combination? For example, is there a possibility of another `gameType: 1,
    gameMonth: 4,`?

Comment: @NinaScholz The wanted result is posted where I say, "I'm needing the end result Object to look like this:"

Comment: @adiga nope, during a given month, there can only be one entry for a given gameType for THAT month.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a default `intialValue` object. This will help you avoid the `if` checks throughout the reduce callback.

Then `reduce` callback is similar to what you're already doing. Just update each `monthByType`

```js
const gamePointsArray=[{gamePlayId:"ggg1",gameType:1,gameMonth:4,gamePoints:4000,},{gamePlayId:"ggg2",gameType:2,gameMonth:2,gamePoints:7000,},{gamePlayId:"ggg3",gameType:2,gameMonth:0,gamePoints:3000,},{gamePlayId:"ggg4",gameType:1,gameMonth:8,gamePoints:25000,},{gamePlayId:"ggg5",gameType:3,gameMonth:8,gamePoints:5000,},{gamePlayId:"ggg6",gameType:3,gameMonth:3,gamePoints:10000,},{gamePlayId:"ggg7",gameType:2,gameMonth:3,gamePoints:5000,}];

const initialValue = { 
  totalPoints: 0,
  monthlyTotals: { ...Array(12).fill(0) },
  monthByType: { ... Array.from({ length: 12 }, _ => ({})) }
}

const output = gamePointsArray.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc.totalPoints += o.gamePoints;
  acc.monthlyTotals[o.gameMonth] += o.gamePoints;
  acc.monthByType[o.gameMonth][o.gameType] = 
      (acc.monthByType[o.gameMonth][o.gameType] || 0) + o.gamePoints;
  return acc;
}, initialValue)

console.log(output)
```

Here's some further explanation on the `initialValue` object:

The `monthlyTotals` property is created using `{ ...Array(12).fill(0) }`  or `Object.assign({}, Array(12).fill(0) )`. This will create an object with indices of the array as keys and value as the key's value

`monthByType` needs to filled with object literals. You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for this. (You cannot use `fill` like above. It will use the same static object's reference in every index which is not desirable)

```js
const arrayWithZeros = Array(12).fill(0),
      monthlyTotals = { ...arrayWithZeros };

const arrayWithEmptyLiterals = Array.from({ length: 12 }, _ => ({}) ),
      monthByType = { ...arrayWithEmptyLiterals }

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayWithZeros))
console.log(JSON.stringify(monthlyTotals))
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayWithEmptyLiterals))
console.log(JSON.stringify(monthByType))
```

Comment: Sorry, but I misunderstood.  There the gamePointsArray can have duplicate types and months and in the result "monthByType" those duplicates need to all be added together.  Your code unfortunately doesn't account for this.  I tried to adjust but I'm coming up short.

Comment: @Clay_F updated for that. Instead of directly assigning `o.gamePoint`, check if there is already a value for that gameType. If yes, use that, else use 0 `(acc.monthByType[o.gameMonth][o.gameType] || 0) + o.gamePoints`

Answer (score 1):

You could take a prefilld array instead of an object and assign or add the values.

```js
const getYear = fn => Array.from({ length: 12 }, fn);

var data = [{ gamePlayId: 'ggg1', gameType: 1, gameMonth: 4, gamePoints: 4000 }, { gamePlayId: 'ggg2', gameType: 2, gameMonth: 2, gamePoints: 7000 }, { gamePlayId: 'ggg3', gameType: 2, gameMonth: 0, gamePoints: 3000 }, { gamePlayId: 'ggg4', gameType: 1, gameMonth: 8, gamePoints: 25000 }, { gamePlayId: 'ggg5', gameType: 3, gameMonth: 8, gamePoints: 5000 }, { gamePlayId: 'ggg6', gameType: 3, gameMonth: 3, gamePoints: 10000 }, { gamePlayId: 'ggg7', gameType: 2, gameMonth: 3, gamePoints: 5000 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { gameType, gameMonth, gamePoints }) => {
        r.total += gamePoints;
        r.monthlyTotals[gameMonth] += gamePoints;
        r.monthByType[gameMonth][gameType] = (r.monthByType[gameMonth][gameType] || 0) + gamePoints;
        return r;
    }, { total: 0, monthlyTotals: getYear(() => 0), monthByType: getYear(() => ({ })) });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```